# Setting MinimumSize Attribute for a Control in a TFS WorkItem

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, workitem

Tools used:

Visual Studio 2008 SP1

Team Explorer

Team Foundation Server Power Tools October 2008 Release.

Using the Process Editor in Visual Studio, I am attempting to set the MinimumSize attribute for a control in a WorkItem template to make the default size of the input area larger.

I am setting the attribute according to this website:

http://msmvps.com/blogs/vstsblog/archive/2007/07/07/undocumented-attributes-for-controlling-the-work-item-form-layout.aspx

No matter what I set this attribute to it has no affect.  I have tried setting the attribute with and without surrounding ().  I've tried different capitalization of the attribute but no luck.

I have verified that the MinimumSize attribute is being correctly set in the associated xml file.

The control (HtmlFieldControl) is currently setup as the second child on a Tab Page.  (The first control is also an HtmlFieldControl.)  I've tried adding a group to the Tab Page such that the hierarchy is TabPage->Group->Column->Control with no success.  I've also tried setting the attribute for the first control with no luck.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that when you preview the form in the process editor it doesn't honor the MinimumSize flag.  Once I uploaded the new work item template to the TFS server it showed up correctly.